# Prevent Factor Conversion to Levels

Tags: r

I'm trying to use `lapply` and `do.call` to combine lists into a `data.frame` object. However, how do I get to prevent factor conversion to levels within the resulting object?
Illustration:

```
dummy<-list(list(data.frame(A=c("Boy","He","Is","Cool"),
                            stringsAsFactors = T)),
                  list(data.frame(B=c("Boy","Not","So","Cool"),
                                  stringsAsFactors = T)))

test1<-lapply(dummy,"[")
as.data.frame(do.call(cbind,test1))
```

Issue:

```
       V1         V2
1 1, 3, 4, 2 1, 3, 4, 2
```

Ignoring the nature of the output, how can I keep the original "values" ie Boy,cool,etc?
Thanks!
Desired Output:

```
A           B
contents    contents
```

I cannot know the number of lists beforehand. I've tried this but it returns NAs:

```
plyr::ldply(test1,function(ele) do.call(cbind,ele))
```

Comment: `identical(test1, dummy)` evaluates to  `TRUE`. What are you trying to do in the `test1` line?

Comment: I'm essentially trying to "extract" each element.

Comment: But you are not doing anything. I've edited the answer. Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: The issue is I cannot specify list number as the actual data has several lists. So I'm looking to "automate" the process.

Comment: Still unclear, do you mean it is nested further? Or does it have longer lists in on the "second" level? If the new edit does not work, I think you should expand your dummy data to more clearly match your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely no conversion has been done:

```
out <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind,test1))
out[[1]]
#[[1]]
#     A
#1  Boy
#2   He
#3   Is
#4 Cool
```

But I find your question unclear since you write "Ignoring the nature of the output". And you explicitly create factors in to `data.frame`, so I'm unsure exactly what you expected. Remember that `factor`s in R are integer vectors with labels. That is what you are seeing in your print.

**Edit**:

```
test1 <- lapply(dummy, "[[", 1)
as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, test1))
#     A    B
#1  Boy  Boy
#2   He  Not
#3   Is   So
#4 Cool Cool
```

**Edit2**
From discussion in the comments, does any of these work?

```
test1 <- lapply(dummy, unlist)
as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, test1))
# Same output as above
```

Alternatively:

```
data.frame(unlist(test1, recursive = FALSE))
# Same output as above
```

Comment: I'll accept although `sapply` did the job. Of course it's hard to provide a good sample. I'll do better next time. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help. Last comment: If you mean sapply did the job, as in `sapply(dummy,"[")`, then you want to call `simplify2array(dummy)` instead (which is what `sapply` calls ultimately). Running `Xapply(dummy, "[")` does not make much sense in itself (as no arguments are passed to the `[` function).